# Mailchimp API send Custom Field

Tags: php, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to send the custom field to mailchimp but not sure how to do this.

If you see below, I am trying to send company information to one of my Audiences but it's not sending through.

[image]

Here is the pasted code as well:

```
 // member information
    $json = json_encode([
        'email_address' => $user_row['email'],
        'status'        => 'subscribed',
        'COMPANY'       =>  $company_info['name'],
        'merge_fields'  => [
            'FNAME'     => $user_row['first_name'],
            'LNAME'     => $user_row['last_name']
        ]
    ]);
```

I have created the custom field inside the mailchimp under targeted audiences. As you can see here:

[image]

So anyone can please help me that what I am doing wrong that company information is not syncing.

On Audiences I am receiving blank company name.

Comment: You shouldn't post screenshots of code. Copy and paste the code into your question instead. I'm not sure this question is a good fit for Stack Overflow, you may want to ask on [su] instead.

Comment: I think my question is fine here and as far as someone gets an idea that what I am trying to do here then they may get back to me with some idea how to do this.

Comment: I hope now it's fine

Comment: how are you using that json variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
 'COMPANY'       =>  $company_info['name'],
```

The above line should be inside the 'merge_fields' like this

```
$json = json_encode([
    'email_address' => $user_row['email'],
    'status'        => 'subscribed',
    'merge_fields'  => [
        'FNAME'     => $user_row['first_name'],
        'LNAME'     => $user_row['last_name'],
        'COMPANY'   => $company_info['name']
    ]
]);
```